# Python, RHS of assignment is "None" (this isn't expected)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

The line is:

```
self.__matchMask[group] = [group].extend(self.__groupMaskImplies[group])
```

The RHS is "None" for some reason, I expect a list.

My understanding of extend is that you can give it any `iterable` and it extends the list with it.

**ADDENDUM**

I might have been being silly! Extend doesn't create a new list, it extends the list it is a method of.

My question is changed to:

Is there a nice way to write what I intend to write? (a nice one-liner)

Comment: you can use `+` to concatenate lists

Comment: If you properly use `extend` it would be a one-liner.